# Compare pair of custom Double class in Scala

Tags: scala

I have defined a `DoubleIn01` class as:

```
implicit class DoubleIn01(val value: Double) extends Ordered[DoubleIn01] {

  require(inBounds(0.0, value, 1.0), s"value $value should be in [0,1]")

  override def toString: String = value.toString
  override def hashCode(): Int = value.hashCode()
  override def compare(that: DoubleIn01): Int = value.compare(that.value)

  override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean =
    obj match {
      case o: Double => value.equals(o.asInstanceOf[Double])
      case o: DoubleIn01 => value.equals(o.asInstanceOf[DoubleIn01].value)
      case _ => false
    }

  def ==(that: Double): Boolean = value == that
}
```

as well as:

```
implicit def DoublePairToDoubleIn01Pair(p: (Double, Double)): (DoubleIn01, DoubleIn01) =
  (DoubleIn01(p._1), DoubleIn01(p._2))
```

But that doesn't seem to be enough to be able to compare a `DoubleIn01` to a `Double` *whichever is on the left or right side of the `==` sign*. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you want to use it? The compiler never attempts any implicit conversion because there's already `==`. So if you trying to use it just like normal implicit conversion(pimp my library pattern). It's impossible.
FYI, Don't forget to put `extends AnyVal` [Value class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).

Comment: `extends AnyVal` is not possible - I tried - because it then doesn't accept the `require` statement, which is the whole point of having this class ... I was hoping my class would seamlessly interoperate with Java and Scala Double types, but it seems that won't happen.

Comment: There is a https://github.com/fthomas/refined library for representing ranges in types. You might find it more suitable for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`==` is not a type-sound operator. See http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/multiversal-equality.html. So it might be not very possible to automatically cast double. You may instead attempt to implement `typedEquals[T]` method, or an operator `===[T]` based on the ideas in multiversal equality.

```
trait Equals[-L, -R] {
  def equals(l: L, r: R): Boolean
}

implicit def equalsRev[R,L](implicit eq: Equals[L, R]): Equals[R, L] = new Equals{
  def equals(l: R, r: L): Boolean = eq.equals(r,l)
}

implicit class EqualityOps[L](l: L){
  def ===[R](r: R)(implicitly eq: Equals[L, R]) = 
    eq.equals(l, r)
}

implicit object DoubleIn01DoubleEq extends Equals[DoubleIn01, Double] {
  def equals(l: DoubleIn01, r: Double): Boolean = (l % 1.0) == r
}

...
val d: DoubleIn01 = 0.2
if(d === 0.5) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You may get rid of `require` saying that all doubles are divided into equivalence classes based on their fractional part:

```
class DoubleIn01(val value0: Double) extends AnyVal with Ordered[DoubleIn01] {
  def value: Double = value0 % 1.0
  override def toString: String = value.toString
  override def hashCode(): Int = value.hashCode()
  override def compare(that: DoubleIn01): Int = value.compare(that.value)

  override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean =
    obj match {
      case o: Double if o >= 0 && o < 1.0 => value.equals(o)
      case _ => false
    }
}
```